# How is the Maybe monad useful in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, monads, option-type

I’m struggling to understand the value of having a Maybe type in TypeScript. I’m trying to make sense of the code example from [this article about implementing your own Maybe type in TypeScript](https://engineering.dollarshaveclub.com/typescript-maybe-type-and-module-627506ecc5c8#950b):

```
enum MaybeType {
  Just = 'maybe-type__just',
  Nothing = 'maybe-type__nothing',
}

interface Just<T> {
  type: typeof MaybeType.Just
  value: T
}

interface Nothing {
  type: typeof MaybeType.Nothing
}

type Maybe<T>
  = Just<T>
  | Nothing

const Nothing = (): Nothing => ({
  type: MaybeType.Nothing,
})

const Just = <T> (value: T): Just<T> => ({
  type: MaybeType.Just,
  value,
})
```

How is this actually useful? I don’t understand how it’s any better than a type just being `T | undefined`.

My (very limited) understanding is the Maybe type can free you from certain runtime errors and eliminate the need for null/undefined checks throughout your code. But aren’t you just trading having `undefined` checks littered throughout your code for having`Nothing` checks littered throughout your code?

In this example, a `Nothing` result has no `value` property, but a `Just` type does. So TypeScript won’t even let me access that value without first making sure that the result is indeed a `Just`. So doesn’t that mean lots of checks everywhere? Why not just keep doing plain-old `undefined` checks? Is the example that I’m looking at just a crummy implementation of the Maybe type?

Clearly I’m missing something and there’s more to it. How does this thing work and how is it useful?

Comment: Besides stylistic reasons, I can think of two differences: (1) you can make these into classes so that you can add methods like `map`, `filter`, `forEach`, and so on, which may be more convenient that writing `if(x !== undefined)` everywhere; and (2) `T | undefined | undefined` is equivalent to `T | undefined`, whereas `Maybe<Maybe<T>>` is not equivalent to `Maybe<T>`, or put another way, `T | undefined` doesn't correctly handle the case where `undefined` is already assignable to `T`.

Answer (score 6):

You're correct in that the code snippet you've included offers very little tangible value above `T | undefined`.

However later on in the linked article the author introduces additional functions such as `maybeMap` and *this* is where the value lies:

```
function maybeMap<A, B> (f: (val: A) => B, m: Maybe<A>): Maybe<B> {
  switch (m.type) {
    case MaybeType.Nothing:
      return Nothing()
    case MaybeType.Just:
      return Just(f(m.value))
  }
}
```

Consider this situation:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: Maybe<number>; // We don't always know their age
}

const bob:Person = {
  name: "Bobby Tables",
  age: Just(23)
}
```

Now imagine we have a people-finding system with the following method:

```
   function findByName(personName: string): Maybe<Person>
```

This nicely represents the fact that we might not find a suitable person, but we're still not getting much value over `Person | undefined`.

But now imagine we need to **obtain the age of the person we find**.

Because `Maybe<T>` is monadic, we can *compose* things to avoid littering our code with checks for `undefined`:

```
  function findAgeOfPerson(personName: string): Maybe<number> {
    const maybePerson = findByName(personName);
    return maybePerson.map((p) => p.age);
  }
```

No `if` statements, no truthiness checks.

If `maybePerson` is `Nothing` then `map` just returns `Nothing`, but if not then `(p) => p.age` does exactly what we need in complete safety.

Comment: Note that you can still write an alternative `function maybeMap<T, S>(x: T | undefined, f: (x: T) => S): S | undefined { return x !== undefined ? f(x) : undefined; }`. Also in your last example you wrote `maybePerson.map(...)` instead of `maybeMap(person, ...)`, which I assume is a typo, but this style *would* be possible if you wrote classes for it.

Comment: You're correct @kaya3 - I was jumping ahead to the end of the linked article where a curried version of the `maybeMap` function is added to `Maybe` to allow this style